# R calculating a formula based on a grouping that needs both subsets from a column e.g beta

Tags: r, data.table

Having a bit of a day for questions today.

Given the following data :=

```
set.seed(1234)
a = data.table(date=seq(ymd('2001-6-30'),ymd('2003-6-30'),by='weeks'),a=rnorm(105),b=rnorm(105),c=rnorm(105))
b = data.table(date=seq(ymd('2001-6-30'),ymd('2003-6-30'),by='weeks'),a=rnorm(105),b=rnorm(105),c=rnorm(105))
a[,idkey:='port']
b[,idkey:='bm']
setkeyv(a,names(a))
setkeyv(b,names(b))
beta=merge(a,b,all=T)
```

If I try and calculate the beta of each column in the portfolio  using the following code

```
beta[,lapply(.SD,function(x)cov(x[idkey=='port'],x[idkey=='bm'])/var(x[idkey=='bm'])),.SDcols=2:5]
```

I get the error

```
Error: is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x) is not TRUE
```

Which I suspect is because the `idkey` column is non.numeric.

The following code works fine

```
for(i in 2:4){
  be = cov(beta[idkey=='port',i,with=F],beta[idkey=='bm',i,with=F])/var(beta[idkey=='bm',i,with=F])
  print(be)
}
```

My question is - how do I calculate the beta using both data.tables without having to go down the clunkier for-loop route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to avoid loop functions. However, you should use binary search:

```
setkeyv(beta,c("idkey", "date"))
sapply(list("a","b","c"),
    function(x) cov(beta['port', ..x], 
                    beta['bm', ..x])/var(beta['bm', ..x]))
```

`..x` means "look up one level"

Comment: Thanks @Roland, in practice there are lots more columns so supplying a list by name isn't practical. That still looks more elegant. Any thoughts on why the earlier `lapply` isn't working?

Comment: Because `idkey` is part of `.SD` and thus passed to `cov`. To reproduce the error: `cov(c("A","B"),c("C","D"))`.